# Simpler Breadcrumb Bar Sample

Tags: c#, wpf, navigation, breadcrumbs

my question is very simple. I am building an app(WPF CSharp) and I need user to give me paths that my app is going to use. Previously I added textboxes to show pathways, however, later I decided that it would be cool to use a Win 7 style Explorer navigation bar, which is a Breadcrumb bar. I found a great open source component for it here (http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tree/WPFBreadcrumbBar.aspx) however, I could not use it in my app. I added references both to Toolbox section and Project>References section. I can also add the control to my WPF window from Toolbox, yet I could not figure out how to fill it, how to change and show items in it etc. With respect to component author, I think article on Codeproject is not very 'understandable'(XAML? I want C# code please) and also PopulateItems event, for instance, did not work for me. So, if someone give me a basic example on how to add items to this bar easily, change items, or shortly, shows me how to make it work, I will appreciate for that,

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I Guess it depends on how you want to present it. If you want to use a tab control to simulate the functionality you could go this route:

http://www.wpfblogger.com/post/BreadCrumb-TabControl-Style-for-WPF-40.aspx

Comment: Have you ever checked out the link I am talking about? I want a sample base on that component if possible. But thanks again :)

Comment: msharpp, I understand. I was trying to offer a simpler alternative. If you are set on this specific component, than I apologize for not addressing that.